# Does DB2 Luw support CHAR semantic?

Tags: sqldatatypes, db2-luw

Oracle supports Byte and Char Semantic when creating table

1. Create table test(n varchar2(10 byte);
2. Create table test(n varchar2(10 char);

Does DB2 Luw support the second create statement with char Semantic?

What can we do in DB2 Luw if we know that some values in the column n may require more than one byte and i don't want to use nvarchar?

Comment: As far as I know DB2 always uses "char semantics" - but the manual should contain that information.

Comment: This statement does not work on my DB2 Lunix V.11.5.6.0 : Create table test(n varchar2(10 char);

Comment: Did you find that syntax in the DB2 manual?

Comment: Not yet,  I'am still searching

Comment: Have you enabled the Oracle semantics? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=compatability-varchar2-nvarchar2

Comment: Do I have to enable the oracle Semantics in my DB2 Luw so that the following statement works and behaves like in Oracle? Create table test(n varchar2(10 char);

Answer (score 0):

Currently supported versions of Db2-LUW when correctly configured to emulate Oracle will then accept the syntax:

`Create table test(n varchar2(10 byte);`

and

`Create table test(n varchar2(10 char);`

By default, Db2-LUW installations will not enable Oracle compatibility, but you can change this by following the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=data-compatibility-features).

Remember that a new database has to be created **after** you set the registry variable **DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR** according to your needs.  This configuration activity is normally done by a DBA.

If your Db2-database does not support this syntax, then Db2-LUW will report the error SQL0104N when you try to use Oracle syntax.